# Javascript closures : Loop inside Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I already know how to loop thanks to closure like this :

```
for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    document.getElementById(more + i).onmouseover = (function(arg1) {
        return function() {
            document.getElementById(arg1).style.display = "block";
        }
    })(i);
}
```

But I'd like now to do a look inside the loop. 
I've got elements of the DOM which must be dynamically attached to other elements. The elements are of the type: `'1text1', '1text2', '1text3',...` and `'2text1', '2text2', '2text3', '3text4'...`
I've tried something like this:

```
var text;
var ktext;
for (var k = 1; k <= last_number; k++) {
    for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        ktext = k + text;
        document.getElementById(ktext + i).onmouseover = (function(arg1, arg2) {
            return function() {
                document.getElementById(arg1 + arg2).style.display = "block";
            }
        })(ktext, i);
    }
}
```

But the loop is partially lost. If I put `alert(ktext + i)` just at the beginning of the `var i` loop, I see: `1text1, 1text2, 1text3, 1text4` then `2text1` (as expected), but not `2text2, 2text3...` as if the second pass of the `var k` loop stops too early.

Comment: You're binding event handlers in loops? Have you considered event delegation?

Comment: You're using the variable `text` before it was initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of closures is unnecessary:

```
for( k=1; k<=last_number; k++) {
  for( i=first; i<=last; i++) {
    document.getElementById(k+text+i).onmouseover = function() {
      this.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

Anyway, your loop may be stopping early if one of the elements doesn't exist on the page. You should check for the element's existence before attempting to assign to it.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to simplify to post my code here and I cut some useful parts: like :  `document.getElementById(arg1+arg2+more).style.display="block"`  The two elements are different

Comment: Well, in any case you can get the ID of the element with `this.id`, so maybe you can use that instead of having to create that many closures. You might even be able to delegate the event so you remove the loops entirely and just do: `document.body.onclick = function(e) {e = e || window.event; var t = e.srcElement || e.target; var id = t.id; /* now do stuff based on the ID */};`